# How to access shared files in two different domains

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain

There are two internal domains, domainA and domainB at my workplace. I could remote into machines from either domains by using respective credentials.

My doubt is if I create a shared folder on domainA with read access to everyone for e.g., `\\server1.domainA.net\sharedfolder`. Will I be able to access this folder by just entering the path likewise from any machine in domainB without entering credentials.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure I want to get in to this.

Comment: So, was the answer a guess or there is a slight ambiguity so that I can provide more information.

Comment: It was the 'Everyone' bit that I'd have to test before I could provide a positive answer. When DomainA trusts DomainB, DomainA trusts the authentication mechanisms of DomainB. There, SSO works. But anonymous files shares are sort of a complicated thing which is what made me less confident in my answer.

Comment: Yes, idea is not to have the credentials window to popup since it has permissions set to everyone. Our development servers are in same env. but this situation arise in UAT which is under release team control. So, it is becoming difficult to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit local security policy on server1 to allow anonymous users to be a part of the "Everyone" group.  (Computer Configuration -> Windows settings -> Security settings -> local policies -> Security Options -> Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772211.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `Anonymous Users` in the NTFS permissions instead of `Everyone`.  This is because starting with Win 2k3 the `Everyone` group no longer includes `Anonymous Users`.

See [Anonymous Users and Traverse Checking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772211.aspx)

You could [Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778182%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) by enabled the Group Policy Setting @ Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options, but that may be more than you want to open up for this.